# What would be the connotative meaning of "deeply grounded in tradition"?

Tags: difference, verbs, word-difference, connotations, polarity-items

What would be the connotative meaning of "deeply grounded in tradition”?

I have looked on various searches and sites and haven't been able to find anything. I have to find an example of denotative meaning and then offer an example of connotative meaning from the following for my communications course:

> Hello, when I was a young girl, my father always told me I could do anything I set my mind to If I coupled vision with determination and hard work. He meant it.
>
> I consider myself fortunate to have learned from the best. Both as an entrepreneur and as a parent.
>
> My father is a man who is **deeply grounded in tradition**. He raised my siblings and me to work hard and strive for excellence in all that we do. He taught us that to inspire and gain respect in life and in business you have to earn it.

Comment: You said, "I have looked on various searches and sites and haven't been able to find anything,” but you neither told  us what you searched for, nor said how the phrases confuses you. Is it that you can’t figure out what it means to be “deeply grounded” in something? Is it that you can’t understand how someone can be “grounded in something”? Do you understand how something might be, say, “grounded in emotion”, but  you can’t figure out how a person could be “grounded in tradition”? When it’s hard to discern what is confusing you, it’s hard to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain that "deeply grounded in tradition" carries any *objective* connotative meaning.  It's a semantically *neutral* description, and more or less synonymous with "traditional", although to a greater degree (i.e., "*very* traditional")

> For members of this religion, wearing sacred objects on their person at all times is **traditional** / **deeply grounded in tradition**.

Because the term is neutral, any *connotation* is based on context and personal opinion.   For example:

> The yearly decoration of houses and trees is **deeply grounded** in the Christmas **tradition**, but some religious individuals believe it's a distraction from the fundamental meaning of the holiday.